# Oracle DB - Application Continuity - How to test it?

Tags: oracle, datasource, oracle12c, replay, continuity

How to Test/POC application continuity concept. I tried making the code to hold connections so that the application is not able get the connections and it tries to get from the pool. I am sure this is not the right way of testing application continuity, but I don't know how to create a proper scenario.

Is it the only way to bring down db while a transaction is in progress ?

I used the below code to simulate AC where a procedure is called 20 times in 20 threads with a new connection everytime. I am creating a scenario where one thread goes and waits for a connection, times-out as not getting connection in time, and then retires to get a connection, IS This a proper AC test. (Below is test class)

```
package com.ac;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.ValidConnection;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new App().acSimulation();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void acSimulation() throws Exception{

            final PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
            pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl");

            System.out.println("connection factory set");

            String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3) (RETRY_COUNT=20)(FAILOVER=ON) " +
             " (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = " +
             " (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))";
            System.out.println("Using URL\n" + URL);
            pds.setURL(URL);
            pds.setUser("system");
            pds.setPassword("oracle");

            pds.setInitialPoolSize(1);
            pds.setMinPoolSize(1);
            pds.setMaxPoolSize(3);
            pds.setConnectionWaitTimeout(10);
            // RAC Features
            pds.setConnectionPoolName("Application Continuity Pool");
            pds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
            // use srvctl config nodeapps to get the ONS ports on the cluster
//          pds.setONSConfiguration("nodes=192.168.100.30:6200,192.168.100.32:6200");

            System.out.println("pool configured, trying to get a connection");

//          final Connection conn = null;


            final Connection conn = pds.getConnection();

            if (conn == null || !((ValidConnection) conn).isValid())  {

              System.out.println("connection is not valid");
              throw new Exception ("invalid connection obtained from the pool");
            }

            if ( conn instanceof oracle.jdbc.replay.ReplayableConnection ) {
              System.out.println("got a replay data source");
            } else {
              System.out.println("this is not a replay data source. Why not?");
            }

            System.out.println("got a connection! Getting some stats if possible");
            oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPoolStatistics stats = pds.getStatistics();
            System.out.println("\tgetAvailableConnectionsCount() " + stats.getAvailableConnectionsCount());
            System.out.println("\tgetBorrowedConnectionsCount() " + stats.getBorrowedConnectionsCount() );
            System.out.println("\tgetRemainingPoolCapacityCount() " + stats.getRemainingPoolCapacityCount());
            System.out.println("\tgetTotalConnectionsCount() " + stats.getTotalConnectionsCount());

            System.out.println(((oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPoolStatistics)pds.getStatistics()).getFCFProcessingInfo());

            System.out.println("Now working");

            int i=0;
            while(i < 20){
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {                     
                        try {
                            seperateInstance(conn, pds);
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.run();
                i++;
            }
    }

    private void seperateInstance(Connection conn, PoolDataSource pds) throws SQLException{
        java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPoolStatistics stats = pds.getStatistics();

            conn = pds.getConnection();

            cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call P_M_emp(?,?)}");
            cstmt.setLong(1, 1);
            cstmt.setString(2, "TEST");
            cstmt.execute();
            System.out.println("Statement executed. Now closing down");
            System.out.println("Almost done! Getting some more stats if possible");

            stats = pds.getStatistics();
            System.out.println("\tgetAvailableConnectionsCount() " + stats.getAvailableConnectionsCount());
            System.out.println("\tgetBorrowedConnectionsCount() " + stats.getBorrowedConnectionsCount() );
            System.out.println("\tgetRemainingPoolCapacityCount() " + stats.getRemainingPoolCapacityCount());
            System.out.println("\tgetTotalConnectionsCount() " + stats.getTotalConnectionsCount());

            System.out.println(((oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPoolStatistics)pds.getStatistics()).getFCFProcessingInfo());
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Closing connection "+ conn);
            cstmt.close();
            conn.close();
            conn = null;

    }

}
```

I got the code from below site and modified a bit to add threads and simulate AC. But I am unable to get a replayable datasource.

https://martincarstenbach.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/playing-with-application-continuity-in-rac-12c/

Comment: `HOST = localhost` - are you sure you're connected to RAC cluster database ?

Comment: I am connecting to a single database instance. As per documentation we can have Application continuity for RAC or can have for Single DB instance also.

Comment: what exactly do you want yo achieve by running the test? I looks like it should show how connection can be dynamically balanced between cluster nodes. PS: you did not change ons servive hostnames `nodes=192.168.100.30:6200,192.168.100.32:6200`

Answer (score 2):

To test Application Continuity you can kill the sessions on the server by doing `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#'` which will simulate a failure.